# TypeScript: All declarations of 'Query' must have identical type parameters

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I get "All declarations of 'Query' must have identical type parameters." error when I hover over "Query" in interface section.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import * as redis from "redis";

declare module "mongoose" {
    interface Query {
        cache():this;
        useCache:boolean;
    }
};

const client = redis.createClient({ url: process.env.REDIS });

client.on("connect", () => console.log("Redis Connection Is Successful!"));
client.on("err", (err) => console.log("Redis Client Error:", err));
client.connect();

//Hooking into mongoose's query generation and execution process
//in order to make the caching reusable in the codebase
const exec = mongoose.Query.prototype.exec;

mongoose.Query.prototype.cache = function() {
    this.useCache = true;
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Query` is initially declared with some generic type parameters in mongoose. TypeScript is just asking you to honor those type parameters in your augmentation:

```
declare module "mongoose" {
    interface Query<ResultType, DocType, THelpers = {}, RawDocType = DocType> {
        cache(): this;
        useCache: boolean;
    }
}
```

You can easily do it by hovering over `Query` and copy pasting the parameters shown:

[image]

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBCCA7A5hCBnApnAZlCEOAIkVXW2IG4AoUSWOAKjgEMM4osATYD-QiS68M1GjW5YAxgBtWXBBG4BXGTlLI0mLMTgBvGnCNxgSGFii5WUnAEVlFgJ4AeAEpYMqmABVHYLAA0cAAiEFK+-kHeABJYMv5QHAC8+gC+Qa6sAO6h4X44KbkRWAB8+obGlVLWABZYABQAlABccDA1fLSVlcrYAMK1WK0ARuhqrEhdxqk0MzRSyBjwssBYZnApwnwAdFJcrOZ9Mqtm9XpwylAyrWAENhgY22sAbtuuAKLBAJIAynCpjVo82Oaxg22Q9WICyQSGkMGIQSaGzK0IwEDU2xkEBQkPcIjgfWQsKkMGAyDgXw4P2UUnuGFwqgAhMRGoDgScwRDiBYoAi4PUeY1kXBUeisJjsbieHwCSD1u8oAQoM0+YK2StQbsiXCmkCAPR66LoADWphQJjMEEU5G0AHIOABHBxQRxwFBrCwHMlINhIbhwLAAD2kylJ5NuYQ8GBoBtMcGgkigbStIFYxpw7Rw1SkHVQnCwvVYwzUFradRFSiww3YWHmi3gQekG2tWmw23sTm2EZgEBg+SewakQLIrfFHZdXYIPb7-l2g2bDKQJO9-KFBkq7R2vSwAxzBTaUAcUyMXBglx9m4wtFStCAA)